# How to use get_post_type_archive_link for a given language?

Tags: multi-language

I try to use get_post_type_archive_link function to retrieve the archives url of a post type but I need to do so for a **specific language**.
Is there a way to achieve this? Is it possible to set the active language programmatically and then call get_post_type_archive_link function?

Comment: Why would the link be different? Are you using a plugin to create different urls for different languages?

Comment: The link usually contains the language code. This is the basic approach toward translating pages...

Answer (score 0):

It's not natively possible but you can generate it.

If your permalink settings is to add a prefix (ex: `http://example.com/fr/archive`) your can use a code link that :

```
function pll_get_post_type_archive_link($post_types = '', $lang = '')
{
    $current_lang = pll_current_language() === pll_default_language() ? '' : '/' . pll_current_language();
    if ($lang != '') {
        $current_lang = $lang == pll_default_language() ? '' : '/' . $lang;
    }

    $re = '/(https?:\/\/[A-z.]*)(.*)/';
    $str = get_post_type_archive_link($post_types);
    $subst = "$1" . $current_lang . "$2";

    return preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ), $lang_code );
```